# Using PhantomJs with RequireJs: modules not loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phantomjs

I have been successfully using `RequireJs` as javascript module loader throughout my current project. Now I would like to take some pictures of the resulting website during a certain period of time so that I can create some sort of a video with `ffmpeg`. For this I have tried to use `PhantomJs`. The phantom script looks like the following:

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length == 1) {
  console.log('Use: phantom '+ args[0] +' URL');
  phantom.exit();
} else if (args.length == 2) {
  var url = args[1];
  console.log('Opening ' + url);
} else {
  console.log('Too many arguments. Use: phantom ' + args[0] + ' URL');
  phantom.exit();
}


// Parameters
var startDelay = 10; // in seconds
var fps = 30;
var duration = 10; // in seconds
var viewportSize = {width: 1024, height:768};

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = viewportSize;

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', url "' + response.url + '")');
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var frame = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      page.render('frames/frame'+(frame++)+'.png', {format: 'png'});
      if(frame > duration*fps) {
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }, 1000/fps);
  }, startDelay*1000);
});
```

The thing is although the website is displayed correctly in the browser, when using `PhantomJs` I simply get empty frames. I have checked what resources are being loaded by `PhantomJs` and none of the `RequireJs` dependencies is loaded at all (have checked both in phantom and server-side). This is what my `index.html` and `main.js` files look like:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg id="map"></svg>
    <canvas id="wind" width="1920" height="1400"></canvas>
    <canvas id="torque" width="1920" height="1400"></canvas>
    <div id="timeline"></div>
  </div>
  <script data-main="src/main" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    torque: 'torque',
    timeSeries: 'time_series',
    wind: 'wind',
    map: 'map',
  }
});

require(['wind', 'torque', 'timeSeries', 'map'], function(wind, torque, timeSeries, map) {
  'use strict';
  // Some stuff...
});
```

For some reason, `main.js` file is loaded but not evaluated, and hence, nothing happens. What might be the reason causing this?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.x is known to hide some errors. Maybe you should try 1.9.8.

Comment: Phantom version is 2.1.1, no errors are thrown. Downgrading to 1.9.8 shows now syntax errors... how well does phantomjs play with es6? I guess this might be the reason

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x hides behind a rock if it hears es6 approaching. PhantomJS 2.x will stop es6 and confuse it until it leaves. Yes, that's the problem. 2.x doesn't even have full support.

Comment: @ArtjomB. feel free to add this as an answer so that I can accept it